# dockerfile: get environment variable from host

Tags: docker

I'm familiar with `ARG`, which allows for arguments to be passed into a dockerfile, like so:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
ARG foo
RUN echo $foo
```

```
$ docker build --build-arg foo=foo .
Sending build context to Docker daemon 2.048 kB
Step 1/3 : FROM ubuntu:latest
 ---> 00fd29ccc6f1
Step 2/3 : ARG foo
 ---> Running in 8f6ddda3254d
 ---> 9c658744762b
Removing intermediate container 8f6ddda3254d
Step 3/3 : RUN echo $foo
 ---> Running in 37bcbf3c5052
foo
 ---> 0e162e793204
Removing intermediate container 37bcbf3c5052
Successfully built 0e162e793204
```

However, what I want is to forward an environment variable from the host into the Dockerfile, without the need for the user to specify the `--build-arg`.  So, for example, I want them to be able to execute this:

```
$ export foo=foo
$ docker build .
```

And get the same result.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use docker-compose to build, with a docker-compose file like the following:

```
my-awesome-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        - FOO=${FOO}
```

Then your user can run `docker-compose build` and the `FOO` variable will be forwarded into the Dockerfile. See: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args

Comment: is it possible without `docker-compose`? my pipeline currently just uses `docker build`, and enhancing it to use `docker-compose` would require rewriting a number of things

Comment: I don't believe so. You might consider writing a wrapper for `docker build`, but that is what docker-compose is.

Comment: Error `Unsupported config option for services.my-awesome-service: 'args'`

Comment: @happy_marmoset i think you probably have an issue with your yaml, or are using an older version of docker-compose